# How can stop automatic block generation in Hyperledger BESU?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-besu

Currently, I have run the default structure of BESU. Which have 4 peers and 1 bootnode.

But Blocks are created automatically without any external transaction and it also affects storage. after 1-2 days storage is fulled.

How I can stop this continuous Block generation in BESU?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change blocktime in Genesis.
Look at the IBFT genesis file in the setup guide and add the blocktime section to genesis, then you must reset the network.

Comment: Thanks! It's working. But it delays the real transactions. Do you have any idea about it ?